# How to scroll one view's height (not page) at a time with a PDF in WKWebView (Swift)

Tags: swift, pdf, uiscrollview, wkwebview

I have a collection of PDFs, some are one page and some are two. I want to see the next visible screen height's worth of the PDF, or scroll to the bottom of the PDF if the remaining height of the PDF is less than the height of the webView. So far, I can only make the webView scroll to the bottom. Here's the function I have...what am I missing?

```
func scrollDown() {
    let scrollView = webview.scrollView
    let contentSize = scrollView.contentSize
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let frameSize = webview.frame.size

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        // Scroll one view's height at a time
        // If the contentSize - offset.y is greater than the frame's height
        if (contentSize.height - contentOffset.y) > frameSize.height {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentOffset.y + (contentSize.height - frameSize.height)), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else needs this. The lesson learned is draw it on paper to understand what's going on...

```
func scrollDown() {
    let scrollView = webview.scrollView
    let contentSize = scrollView.contentSize
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let frameSize = webview.frame.size
    let frameHeight = frameSize.height

    // Next view's height
    let heightOffset = frameSize.height + contentOffset.y
    let offsetToBottom = contentSize.height - frameSize.height

    if contentOffset.y + frameHeight > contentSize.height - frameHeight {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offsetToBottom), animated: true)
        print("Should be scrolling to bottom")
    } else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightOffset), animated: true)
        print("Should be scrolling by one page")
    }
}
```